# Dualizing module for $\operatorname{Aut}(F_n)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

In *The complex of free factors of a free group* [(pdf at Hatcher's page)](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Papers/FCn.pdf), Hatcher and Vogtmann defined a simplicial complex $FC_n$ called the ``complex of free factors'' of the free group $F_n$. They proved that $FC_n$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $(n-2)$-spheres. They call the top reduced homology group of this complex the Steinberg module of $\operatorname{Aut}(F_n)$ and ask if it is a rational dualizing module for $\operatorname{Aut}(F_n)$. That is, they ask if: $$H^i(\operatorname{Aut}(F_n);\mathbb Q) \cong H_{2n-2-i}(\operatorname{Aut}(F_n);\tilde H_{n-2}(FC_n;\mathbb Q)).$$ Has there been any progress on this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In our paper [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.03102), Himes, Miller, Nariman, and myself prove that Hatcher-Vogtmann’s question has a negative answer, at least for $n=5$. It also probably has a negative answer for larger $n$, but our ignorance of the unstable cohomology of $Aut(F_n)$ prevents us from proving this via our techniques.  I do not know any reasonable conjecture as to what the dualizing module is.